# How to prevent restarting of the application when tab's position is turned (horizontal to vertical or vice versa)?

Tags: android

I am working on Travel app. I'm fetching data from gps and displaying it on the screen. The data vanishes when I turn my tab's position to horizontal or vertical.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

use [configChanges](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#configChanges) in the manifest

```
 android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

Comment: if i put this line, then I'll not be able to retrieve the data from the previous screen.